# Apricity OS not show in grub

Tags: ubuntu, grub2

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed ( updated through 15.04 -> 15.10 ) . and Windows 10 Dual booted along with it .

I tried to Apricity OS rc1 ( md5sum -> 58ad9c6172a2f45e31bd756d83107058 ) to my laptop and it gave several errors , after that I found I have to add fat32 formatted boot/efi partition instead adding /boot to the installation.
1GB-> boot/efi
50GB-> /home
50GB-> / 
8GB -> swap

so the installation process worked perfectly without any errors .

but the problem is grub only showing ubuntu no any other OS , I can forget about windows , since it can be recover . 
but still need to get ApricityOS to the grub which is installed in sda10 . 
since I'm considering moving to Arch from ubuntu , think Apricity OS will be good move to initiate with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that `os-prober` is installed in Ubuntu. If not:

```
sudo apt-get install os-prober
```

Double check that your Grub config is stored in the usual place:

```
ls /boot/grub/
grub.cfg
```

Then generate a new one:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

*Hopefully* this should solve the problem. If not, let us know.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. this should work also . 
I again run the boot repair in the ubuntu and fixed it using recommended fix option .

Comment: Glad to hear it mate, all the best.